# How to set NULL argument in R function?

Tags: r, function, plot

I am trying to build a R function such that:

```
xplot<-function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g=NULL, h, ...){
    par(mafrow=c(2,2))
    plot(a,b)#plot1
    plot(b,c)#plot2
    plot(e,f)#plot3
    if (!is.null(g)){plot(g,h} #plot4
}
```

I would like the output such that:

```
xplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,h)
```

output plot1,2,3, while

```
xplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,g, h)
```

shows plot1,2,3,4. But I don't how to pass the `g=NULL` smoothly. When I test my function I either have to specify `g=NULL`, or come out with an error.

Comment: define function as `function(a, b, c, d, e, f, h, g=NULL, ...)` and call it as `xplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,h)` and `xplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,h,g)`

Comment: @ChinmayPatil Add that as an answer...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define function as `function(a, b, c, d, e, f, h, g=NULL, ...)` and call it as `xplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,h)` and `xplot(a,b,c,d,e,f,h,g)`